# How to determine Plucker coordinates of Infinite dimension Sato Grassmannian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, grassmannian

I wish to determine Plucker coordinates of Infinite dimension Sato Grassmannian. I've been reading the original paper by Sato and other related works, but couldn't understand few things

Do Plucker coordinates of infinite dim Sato Grassmanian also fulfill Plucker relations ? If yes, how do we go about determining those Plucker relations ?